# SMTP mail settings

Tags: 14.04, email, smtp

I use Ubuntu 14.04. I was sending a document in pdf format through LibreOffice email for the first time. I get prompts asking me for server configurations.  I did not know the format for yahoo SMTP mail so I made an educated guess. I think I found the right format later on. My question is, How do I go back into this configuration and edit my answers?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: LibreOffice does not have an email client. If you choose to send a document by email (via LibreOffice's menu), it will open your email client. If you are using the default one that comes with Ubuntu, that'd be Thunderbird (which should recognize a Yahoo email address just fine).

Comment: That comment is almost a complete answer - if you add how to get into account settings in Thunderbird (last I knew, Menu -> Arrow next to Options -> Account settings) you could submit it as answer IMHO.

Comment: @AibaraIduas: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice does not have an email client. If you choose to send a document by email (via LibreOffice's menu), it will open your email client.

The default mail client that comes with Ubuntu is Thunderbird. If you attempt to add a Yahoo email account, Thunderbird will automatically recognize the correct settings.

Comment: Going through my "schmucks" answers that didn't get any upvotes...  So finally you got one!  ;-)